# Axis Label Alignment in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem setting the alignment of the xAxis labels so that it looks alright.
the position of first and last labels are not aligned with the Axis extremes but rather has moved outside of the chart area itself.

I have tried many thing such as setting the overflow to Justify and also tried to position the Labels but in highcharts one can apply a setting such as alignment or x position to all the labels. If only there was a way to actually align the first and last label separately one to the left the other to the right, it would be perfect.
Here is the JSfiddle:

```
labels: {
            step: 11,
            maxStaggerLines : 1
        }
```

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/w7FDP/)

PS. :To show only first and last label, I use steps.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or a piece of code that shows your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use `overflow: 'justify'` to handle overflowing labels on the x axis as shown in this example (from the github repo https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      plotBorderWidth: 1
    },

    title: {
      text: null
    },

    xAxis: [{
      type: 'datetime',
      labels: {
        overflow: 'justify'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Justified labels'
      }
    }, {
      type: 'datetime',
      linkedTo: 0,
      opposite: true,
      title: {
        text: 'Non-justified labels'
      }
    }],



    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: null
      },
      labels: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },

    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6],
      pointStart: (new Date()).setUTCHours(0),
      pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
      showInLegend: false
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 300px; width: 500px"></div>
```

The issue here is that `overflow: 'justify'` doesn't seem to work when combined with the `step` directive (I tried to add `step: 6` to the above fiddle and had the same problem that you have). I would use a workaround by creating a number of labels that is equal to the number of steps +1 (or number of steps=number of labels minus 1).

Another solution that works in all cases is to add `rotation: 90` as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w7FDP/1/).

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {},
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan 2 2013', 'Jan 3 2013', 'Jan 4 2013', 'Jan 5 2013', 'Jan 6 2013', 'Jan 7 2013', 'Jan 8 2013', 'Jan 9 2013',
        'Jan 10 2013', 'Jan 11 2013', 'Jan 12 2013', 'Jan 13 2013'
      ],
      labels: {
        step: 11,
        maxStaggerLines: 1,
        rotation: 90
      }
    },

    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 234.4, 134.5, 160.4, 134.6, 154.3]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
```

Comment: rotation 90 is out of question because of UI design that we have. and yes unfortunately overflow justify doesnt work with steps.. I wonder if extending highcharts, getting the Axis positions and then realigning the labels individually could be an option..

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of ways how you can resolve it:

- set `marginRight` higher, for example to 25px
- set `width` for labels, so they will be wrapped

And in general, I would advice to use `datetime` xAxis, when using data based on a dates. Categories are created rather to handle.. categories, like fruits, cars, etc. Example, I would advice to use: http://jsfiddle.net/32cWY/

Comment: The Problem is that, we change the labels based on some criteria, we dont use the original datetime. Therefore we need to use category.

Comment: Still in your jsfiddle, The first label goes beyond the boundry of the yAxis. The first label should exactly starts from the Origin rather than couple of pixels to the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 chart: {
         type: 'column',
         marginRight:110
        },
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the only hint that helped me get the answer I was searching for. I was required to make the yAxis labels left aligned. chart: { marginLeft: 80 }, yAxis: { labels: { align: 'left', x: -78 } }